# Effects of calling SetThreadUILanguage

Tags: multithreading, winapi, internationalization, windows-mui

What are the effects of calling SetThreadUILanguage in an applicaton? Will it cause captions like "OK" and "CANCEL" on a MessageBox to appear in the language set through this API?

If the captions do appear in the set language, do they require a localized version of the OS in that language or is it sufficient to have an MUI (Multilinguistic User interface pack) / LIP (Language interface pack) on top of an English OS.

Thanks,
Ranjit

Answer (score 2):

> Will it cause captions like "OK" and "CANCEL" on a MessageBox to appear in the language set through this API

No. These come from the OS, and are always in the language of the OS.
If you have a localized OS, or MUI or LIP installed, they will show in the current language of the OS UI.

SetThreadUILanguage affects the loading of the resource only dlls by the application calling it, if the application uses the standard MUI API.

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies it for me.